# View PDF file in fullscreen mode using PDFJS

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using pdfjs-dist module to display pdf file in a modal popup. I can apply some features: change/ goto page, zoom, etc ... 
 I want to view pdf file in fullscreen or presentation mode just like the demo of pdfjs:

> https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

I have looked into pdfjs source code but I do not know how to enter fullscreen/presentation mode.

Answer (score 5):

```
<iframe height='100%' width='100%' scrolling='no' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen src='./viewer.html?file=./PDFFile.PDF'></iframe>
```

`allowfullscreen` and `webkitallowfullscreen` do the trick for presentation mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add page number to open pdf in full-screen in separate tab.
For Example

```
<a href="your URL#page=2">Open yourpdf.pdf with PDF.js in new tab</a>
```